# Adapt the formating pattern of a string if the last variable is an empty string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a class that has multiple string patterns as class attributes.
The patterns are later used to create strings.

```
class Main:

 pattern_for_a = "{} {} {}"
 pattern_for_b = "{} {}-{}"
 pattern_for_c = "{}-{} {}"
......................

 def do_a(*args, **kwargs):
   ............
   c = pattern_for_a.format(a1,a2,r)
```

This class have multiple subclasses which in some cases overwrites the patterns.Ex:

```
class B(Main):

 pattern_for_a = "{}:{} {}"
 pattern_for_b = "{}-{}{}"
 pattern_for_c = "{}{} {}"
```

This works well when all 3 variables have a real value. But there are cases, when the
last variables is and empty string. In this special case the separator needs also to be removed.

Example:

```
pattern_for_a = "{}:{}-{}"
a="x" b="y" c="z"
Result: "x:y-z"
```

```
pattern_for_a = "{}:{}-{}"
a="x" b="y" c=""
Result: "x:y-"
```

The result contains also the separator `-`(in this case, the separator can be any char/string), and I want to be `x:y`

I can duplicate the patterns to have a set with all 3 variables available, and a separate set of patterns for when the last variable is just empty string and combine with `if else` conditions or just conditions to solve it.

But because I have multiple patterns and need to check in multiple places I don't think the solution is optimal.

I'm looking for a solution to solve it without using duplicate patterns and many `ifs`. Needs to work in python2.7 and 3.*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something slightly different. I don't think it's a problem to specify only two patterns, and I think it makes things a bit more configurable. The key is not to have to change how the formatting works.

```
class Main:
    _pattern_a = ("{}:{} {}", "{}:{}")

    def pattern_for(self, name, a, b, c=None):
        long, short = getattr(self, f"_pattern_{name}")
        if c is None:
            return short.format(a, b)
        return long.format(a, b, c)

class B(Main):
    _pattern_a = ("{}:{}-{}", "{}:{}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it without if’s, then conditionally add the third format part:

```
a=123
b=456
c=""
pattern_for_a = "{}:{}"+(c!="")*"-{}"
print(pattern_for_a.format(a,b,c))
```

The string multiplicator will be 0, if c is empty, and 1 otherwise

Comment: I used the name a,b,c for simplicity the actual variable names can variate. If `c` or other name is used in the subclass will be strongly coupled with the functions in the main class. A change of name in main class needs to be propagated to all subclassses so the solution doesn't scale.

Comment: @user3541631 variable names doesn't matter. I just wanted to make a simple version of your code. The point here is how to make the formatting dynamic